# How to use a Trapper Item without Zabbix S

Tags: azure, zabbix, azure-alerts

How do I send a JSON payload to a Zabbix Trapper Item without using Zabbix Sender?

I see the documentation on [how to format the sender request](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/items/trapper) and I see the documentation related to [the header](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/protocols/header_datalen), but I haven't found how to use the header with a JSON payload.

My goal is to send Azure Activity Logs to Zabbix a Trapper Item using Azure Alerts.

I don't want to setup a Script Item or equivalent that would pull the information from the Azure API, as I would then have to worry about hitting the query limit for the Azure Management APIs and being throttled by the Azure platform.

How is the header incorporated into the request payload?

Comment: As you have already asked the same question on the Zabbix forum, posting a reference link here to help other community members: [How to use a Trapper Item without Zabbix Sender](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/433108-how-to-use-a-trapper-item-without-zabbix-sender)

Comment: thanks, although you can see how much traction I'm getting over there.

As long as we're consolidating my previous references, I had actually started with a post in the Zabbix subreddit

[Zabbix Webook/Trapper functionality](https://www.reddit.com/r/zabbix/comments/pz8mod/zabbix_webooktrapper_functionality/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an implementation of the same protocol, for example:

- in go: https://github.com/adubkov/go-zabbix
- in python: https://github.com/adubkov/py-zabbix

and put that in a cloud function to send the payload to Zabbix.

Comment: You are both not answering my question and proving my case.  I'm asking where the header goes in the payload; not for a pre-existing script to implement.

And yet, these two Github projects are not official Zabbix implementations of the sender, so clearly the information exists somewhere that's not well-documented or documented in a publicly accessible/findable location

If I have to go down the route of creating a function in the cloud to do the work, at an increased cost to me, I'm happy to do so.  However, I'd like to rule out other options first.

Comment: Header and payload goes in the packet, you can't put a header in the payload of course. You also can't send Azure Alerts with Zabbix protocol without a cloud function, as far as I know. You could install a third party software to translate webhooks calls to Zabbix protocol, if that's cheaper. Looks like you are trying to use HTTP protocol, while you should be using Zabbix protocol.